IPC Dialog in ElectronJS showing up behind main window after activated a second time
I'm using Electron and when I call the IPC dialog for the first time it shows up on top which is great but when I launch it any time after that it will now show up behind the main window which is not good as I will have the app be launched in fullscreen.
I have tried parenting the dialog to the main window but it continues with this problem until I restart the app, here is my current code:
main.js
ipcMain.handle('dialog:openDirectory', async () => {
                const { canceled, filePaths } = await dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, {
                    properties: ['openDirectory']
                })

                if (canceled) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    return filePaths[0]
                }
            })

System Info:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Electron: ^29.1.5
NodeJS: v18.18.2
